# Can I have more than one favicon.ico on my site?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a favicon.ico in my root directory. This now shows up when people browse to my site. I notice that I can also use the following:

```
<link
rel="icon"
href="[URL]
type="image/x-icon"
/>
<link
rel="shortcut
icon" href="[URL]
type="image/x-icon"
/>
```

Is there any advantage in adding this to my master page?

Can I use this syntax to specify different favico's for different pages on my site?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it. (One different per page). But IMHO is better to provide consistency.

1. If you do that on your Master Page all the pages will share the same one (recommended).
2. Yes, you can specify as many as you want BUT need to provides the respective header declaration on each page.